# python error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror

I got this error when I run it.please help me,thank you!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PythonClient\ChartReport.py", line 64, in <module>
    DAVIDenrich(listF = './list1.txt', idType = 'AFFYMETRIX_3PRIME_IVT_ID', listName = 'list1', category = 'abcd,BBID,BIOCARTA,COG_ONTOLOGY,INTERPRO,KEGG_PATHWAY,OMIM_DISEASE,PIR_SUPERFAMILY,SMART,SP_PIR_KEYWORDS,UP_SEQ_FEATURE')
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PythonClient\ChartReport.py", line 45, in DAVIDenrich
    rowDict = dict(row)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

code is:

```
def DAVIDenrich(listF, idType, bgF='', resF='', bgName = 'Background1',listName='List1', category = '', thd=0.1, ct=2):
    from suds.client import Client
    import os

    if len(listF) > 0 and os.path.exists(listF):
        inputListIds = ','.join(open(listF).read().split('\n'))
        print 'List loaded.'        
    else:
        print 'No list loaded.'
        raise

    flagBg = False
    if len(bgF) > 0 and os.path.exists(bgF):
        inputBgIds = ','.join(open(bgF).read().split('\n'))
        flagBg = True
        print 'Use file background.'
    else:
        print 'Use default background.'

    client = Client('http://david.abcc.ncifcrf.gov/webservice/services/DAVIDWebService?wsdl')
    print 'User Authentication:',client.service.authenticate('yourEmail@your.org')

    listType = 0
    print 'Percentage mapped(list):', client.service.addList(inputListIds,idType,listName,listType)
    if flagBg:
        listType = 1
        print 'Percentage mapped(background):', client.service.addList(inputBgIds,idType,bgName,listType)

    print 'Use categories:', client.service.setCategories(category)
    chartReport = client.service.getChartReport(thd,ct)
    chartRow = len(chartReport)
    print 'Total chart records:',chartRow

    if len(resF) == 0 or not os.path.exists(resF):
        if flagBg:
            resF = listF + '.withBG.chartReport'
        else:
            resF = listF + '.chartReport'
    with open(resF, 'w') as fOut:
        fOut.write('Category\tTerm\tCount\t%\tPvalue\tGenes\tList Total\tPop Hits\tPop Total\tFold Enrichment\tBonferroni\tBenjamini\tFDR\n')
        for row in chartReport:
            rowDict = dict(row)
            categoryName = str(rowDict['categoryName'])
            termName = str(rowDict['termName'])
            listHits = str(rowDict['listHits'])
            percent = str(rowDict['percent'])
            ease = str(rowDict['ease'])
            Genes = str(rowDict['geneIds'])
            listTotals = str(rowDict['listTotals'])
            popHits = str(rowDict['popHits'])
            popTotals = str(rowDict['popTotals'])
            foldEnrichment = str(rowDict['foldEnrichment'])
            bonferroni = str(rowDict['bonferroni'])
            benjamini = str(rowDict['benjamini'])
            FDR = str(rowDict['afdr'])
            rowList = [categoryName,termName,listHits,percent,ease,Genes,listTotals,popHits,popTotals,foldEnrichment,bonferroni,benjamini,FDR]
            fOut.write('\t'.join(rowList)+'\n')
        print 'write file:', resF, 'finished!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DAVIDenrich(listF = './list1.txt', idType = 'AFFYMETRIX_3PRIME_IVT_ID', listName = 'list1', category = 'abcd,BBID,BIOCARTA,COG_ONTOLOGY,INTERPRO,KEGG_PATHWAY,OMIM_DISEASE,PIR_SUPERFAMILY,SMART,SP_PIR_KEYWORDS,UP_SEQ_FEATURE')
    DAVIDenrich(listF = './list2.txt', idType = 'AFFYMETRIX_3PRIME_IVT_ID', listName = 'list2', category = 'abcd,BBID,BIOCARTA,COG_ONTOLOGY,INTERPRO,KEGG_PATHWAY,OMIM_DISEASE,PIR_SUPERFAMILY,SMART,SP_PIR_KEYWORDS,UP_SEQ_FEATURE')
    DAVIDenrich(listF = './list2.txt', bgF = './list1.txt', idType = 'AFFYMETRIX_3PRIME_IVT_ID', bgName = 'Background1', listName = 'list2', category = 'abcd,BBID,BIOCARTA,COG_ONTOLOGY,INTERPRO,KEGG_PATHWAY,OMIM_DISEASE,PIR_SUPERFAMILY,SMART,SP_PIR_KEYWORDS,UP_SEQ_FEATURE')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
chartReport = client.service.getChartReport(thd,ct)
```

add

```
chartReport = filter(None, chartReport)
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point, `for row in chartReport` returns a row that is `None`, which you cannot convert to a dict with `dict()`.

Either figure out why this iterator is including `None` values, or check if it is `None` before processing it and skip it if it is.